# Find curve parametrization

Tags: parametric, line-integrals, parametrization

I am asked to find the work of $f(x, y, z) = (x, z, 2y)$ through the curve given by the intersection of two surfaces. I have been doing a series of exercises on this and my question has simply to do with the parametrization of the curve.

The two surfaces are:

$\{(x, y, z) \in R^3 : x = y^2 + z^2\}$ and

$\{(x, y, z) \in R^3 : x + 2y = 3\}$

Although I managed to calculate a function $g$ such that $g(\alpha) = (3-2\alpha, \alpha, \sqrt{3 - \alpha^2 - 2\alpha})$ gives me points on both those surfaces, I am pretty sure there is a nicer parametrization for proceeding to calculate the integral, involving modified polar coordinates. Even with this one, I could only find that $\alpha \le \frac{3}{2}$, leaving me wondering what the lower bound for $\alpha$ is.

Comment: It is the intersection of a paraboloid and a slant plane. As $(1,1,0)$ and $(3,0,\sqrt{3})$ belong to the two surfaces, we have an ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of the two surfaces is given by the equation : $$y^2+z^2-x=3-2y-x$$
or, $$z^2+y^2+2y-3=z^2+(y+1)^2=4$$ which is the equation of a circle in the yz-plane.
We have the parametrization $$z=2cost$$, $$y=-1+2sint$$ and $$x=5-4sint$$

Finaly : $\gamma(t)=(5-4sint,-1+2sint,2cost)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ g(\alpha) = (3-2\alpha, \alpha, \sqrt{3 - \alpha^2 - 2\alpha}) = (3-2\alpha, \alpha, \sqrt{(\alpha+3) (1-\alpha) })$$

is the simplest you can get. You eliminated single term $x$ , put in $ y= \alpha$ and found remaining $z$ in terms of parameter $\alpha$ , I cannot find a simpler parameterization.

Comment: using this what is the lower bound for $\alpha$?

Comment: Looking under the radical sign,lower limit -3, upper limit +1, domain for  an ellipse.